# Accessing the "many" side from the "one" side effectively

Tags: django, django-orm, many-to-one

Considering the following models:

```
class ManySide(django.db.models.Model):
    one_side = models.ForeignKey(
        to=OneSide, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="related_one_side"
    )

class OneSide(django.db.models:model):
    # not containing any field relevant here

    def many_side_elements(self):
        pass # ?
```

What should I include in method `many_side_elements` so that calling it from a `OneSide` Model instance would list a queryset of `ManySide` elements?

[Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) imply that given `o` is a `OneSide` isntance, `o.many_side_set.all()` should work but it returns an error in shell.

My current solution is the following:

```
from django.apps import apps

[...]

def many_side_elements(self):
    ManySideModel = apps.get_model('<app_name_here>', 'ManySide')

    val = ManySideModel.objects.filter(one_side=self)
```

But I'm concerned it's ineffective since it requires importing the other Model. Actually it caused a circular dependency error message in my project, hence the `get_model` usage.

Is there any better way? Or `xy_set` should work in the first place? Then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about o.related_one_side.all()? Since you created the related_name, the builtin manyside_set is not going work. See: https://youtu.be/YIJI5U0BWr0?t=502

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: @AMG oh my god you're right! I used `related_name` prop totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the model field with a related name, the related name overrides the _set queryset.

In your case
`o.related_one_side.all()` should work without the need for another def.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

> You can override the FOO_set name by setting the related_name parameter in the ForeignKey definition. For example, if the Entry model was altered to blog = ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries'), the above example code would look like this: b.entries.all()

Comment: Yes, it solved the issue perfectly. Thank you! Sadly the way I was wording the issue yielded no result in search engines...hopefully this can help others, too.